# Why Room is only loading after restarting app in JetPack Compose

Tags: android, kotlin, android-room, android-jetpack-compose

I have this project where I add habits throught a dialog but the inputs only appear on the lazyColumn after I restart the app. The same is happening in different parts of the app, I believe the problem must be the same. Why is this happening?

below is the code:

```
@AndroidEntryPoint
class CalendarListFragment : Fragment() {

    private val viewModel: UserViewModel by viewModels()

override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View {
        return ComposeView(requireContext()).apply {
            setContent {
    
           val habitList = viewModel.habitList.value
           val isDialogOpen = remember { mutableStateOf(false) }

                             LazyColumn(Modifier.padding(8.dp)) {
                                items(items = habitList) { habit ->
                                    HabitCard(
                                        habit = habit,
                                        viewModel,
                                        dateSelected.value,
                                        datesWithHabits
                                    )
                                }
                            }


@Composable
fun AlertDialogComponent(
    isDialogOpen: MutableState<Boolean>,
    text: MutableState<String>,
    viewModel: UserViewModel,
) {
    if (isDialogOpen.value) {
        AlertDialog(
            onDismissRequest = { isDialogOpen.value = false },
            
confirmButton = {
                Button(onClick = {
                    isDialogOpen.value = false
                    val habit = Habit(text.value)
                    viewModel.insertHabit(habit)
                    }
                 }


@Composable
fun HabitCard(
    habit: Habit,
){
            Text(
                text = habit.habit)
}
```

the viewModel

```
@HiltViewModel
class UserViewModel @Inject constructor(
    private val repository: MainRepository
) : ViewModel() {

    val habitList: MutableState<List<Habit>> = mutableStateOf(listOf())

    init {
        getAllHabits()
    }

    fun getAllHabits(){
        viewModelScope.launch {
            habitList.value = repository.getAllHabits()
        }
    }
}
```

the repository

```
class MainRepository @Inject constructor(
    private val userDao: UserDao
){
suspend fun insertHabit(habit: Habit) = userDao.insertHabit(habit)

    suspend fun getAllHabits() = userDao.getAllHabits()
}
```

the Dao

```
@Dao
interface UserDao {

    @Insert(onConflict = OnConflictStrategy.REPLACE)
    suspend fun insertHabit(habit: Habit)

    @Transaction
    @Query("SELECT * FROM habits")
    suspend fun getAllHabits(): List<Habit>

}
```

How can I fix it?

Comment: Where do you assign the updated values of the database to your lazyColumn? You could return livedata or flow from your Database instead of List<Habit> and observe this object. The observer triggers when the database has changed.

Comment: isn't the mutableState in the viewModel suposed to do that and recompose after changing?

Comment: Yes mutablestate would recompose it, but mutablestate is never updated.  You are only inserting into the database but never assign the updated list to the mutablestate. I just assume you do that, because you are calling viewmodel.insert, but there is no insert function in your viewmodel, only in the repository

Comment: That was it. Found my mistake. Thanks

Comment: I think that this [article](https://medium.com/firebase-tips-tricks/how-to-read-data-from-room-using-kotlin-flow-in-jetpack-compose-7a720dec35f5), will help.